# Is there a way to get a url for a resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a resource such as @post, is there a way to get the url to the path to that resource such as:

```
@post.to_url
url_for(@post)
path_to(@post)
@post.to_path...
```

you get the ideal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a resource like `@post`, `url_for` will return the path.

```
url_for(@post) #=> "/posts/1"
```

From the console:

```
app.url_for(@post) #=> "http://www.example.com/posts/1"
app.post_path(@post) #=> "/posts/1"
```

See:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: It doesn't work in the Rails console. Is that because I need to include something like ActionController?

Comment: From the Rails console, use `app.url_for(@post)`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @mysmallidea

Comment: How can I use it in a model?

Comment: I got it with   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers